# Styling adjacent/sibling element with a:visited not working

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <a class = "content" href= "........">
     // a lot of different divs in here
  </a>
  <div class = "label">
     Label
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply styling to the `label` class if the link of class `content` is visited.

My CSS is the following:

```
.content:visited + .label {
   color: gray;
}
```

However, even when my link is visited, the label still shows unvisited state. After some research I found "If you use sibling selector such as :visited + span, the adjacent element will be styled as if the link were unvisited" at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Privacy_and_the_:visited_selector.

Is there any workaround with pure CSS to make my use case work? Seems like this would be a common scenario.

Comment: Classes in css need to be prefixed with ".", i.e. `content` -> `.content`

Comment: Made edit for clarity. However, still same issue with the correct prefixing.

Comment: Reading through that article, seems not for privacy concerns.